# Mining Profitability

Tags: mining-hardware

My friend's dad recently started mining BTC with his gaming PC while he's not using it. As far as I can see, this kind of mining is not profitable anymore. He gets 40 Mh/s on average and apparently has made about $10 so far. I tried busting out my old Block Erupter USB miner which gets about 250 Mh/s and it hasn't made anywhere near *$1*. I'm wondering if he's just messing with me or if I'm missing something important. He could be mistaken about what coin he's mining but I'm pretty sure it's BTC.

Comment: Some quick math suggests that mining Bitcoin at 40 MH/s would produce 4 cents per year in revenue.

Comment: See this answer. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13674/1878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mining Bitcoin at 40 MH/s is not profitable.

Unless you get free electricity and consider 4 cents a year profit, there is no point mining Bitcoin with that hash rate.

Does your friend's dad have $10 in Bitcoin from mining with that hash rate? Simply put, no. Your friend's dad could have, however, been mining a different cryptocurrency without knowing. 40 MH/s mining Ethereum produces $3 a day.

Comment: I'm not sure. I know he's using the Nicehash miner but I don't know if that can mine ethereum or not.

Comment: Nicehash miner can make about $10 a day mining different profitable coins at `40MH/s`.